# How to change provisioned throughput of GSI in DynamoDB using Java api

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

It's easy to change provisioned throughput for table using java DynamoDB api like this:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateTable(tableName,new ProvisionedThroughput(read,write));
```

Global secondary indices (GSIs) have their own provision values independent from the base table. Is there a way to manage them using java api like we do with tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the other [updateTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#updateTable(com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.UpdateTableRequest)) method and pass your instance of `UpdateTableRequest`.

Add a [GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdate.java) to it and set the new provisioned throughput.

Comment: OMG they say java is verbose... but well api developers are much more verbose for sure! Thx.
http://pastebin.com/LjPLV0Xd

Comment: @user3231055 I think there is an error in your pastebin since you're not specifying which index will be affected by the update; just use `.withIndexName(<index_name>)` method before `.withProvisionedThroughput`.

Comment: Thx Marco, I already fixed that many months ago, but you are very attentive anyway )